# Image is shown in half when using it as SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to convert an image to SCNNode, but the image always shown in half like this after adding it as child node to part(node) of the car object that I have and the original image is full circle like that one on the black image.
This is what I've tried.

```
        let translationResult = result.localCoordinates
        let nodeImage = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.8, height: 0.8))
        nodeImage.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageOfDamage[0]
        nodeImage.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .fill
        nodeImage.position = translationResult
        nodeImage.eulerAngles.x = 2.8 + Float.pi
        nodeImage.eulerAngles.y =  Float.pi + 3.16
        nodeImage.scale = SCNVector3(0.5,0.5,0.5)
        nodeImage.name = "DamageNodeImage"
        nodeSearched.addChildNode(nodeImage)
```

[image]

The Original One:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the image simply intersecting with the other object and part of it gets occluded?

Comment: @mnuages Thank you for you answer.
I think it intersect with the other node but I don't know why that keep happening on each node. I tried to change its Euler angel but nothing happened.

Comment: It needed some math only to the y and x axis.
This answer helped me:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777901/scenekit-adding-scnnode-on-another-scnnode